# Angular 2 divs same row 1 below

Tags: html, css, angular

Good Evening,
I have a project in angular and I want to make the styling I just do not have much knowledge from css to do it.Specifically, I have roughly 3 divs And I want the 2 to be in the same row and the other to be exactly below with a size equal to 2 above.
The divs are card, tabel and map.
The top left has the information of the item, the top right has the table and the bottom I want to have the map.

More specifically, I want it that way:

[image]

So far I'm here:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="row">
      <aside class="col-sm-5 border-right">
        <article class="gallery-wrap">
          <div class="img-big-wrap">
            <div> <a href="#"><img [src]="" /></a></div>
          </div> <!-- slider-product.// -->
          <div class="img-small-wrap">
            <div class="item-gallery"> <img [src]="" /> </div>
            <div class="item-gallery"> <img [src]="" /> </div>
            <div class="item-gallery"> <img [src]="" /> </div>
            <div class="item-gallery"> <img [src]="" /> </div>
          </div> <!-- slider-nav.// -->
        </article> <!-- gallery-wrap .end// -->
      </aside>

      <aside class="col-sm-7">
        <article class="card-body p-5">
          <h1 class="title mb-3">{{item.name}}</h1>

          <p class="price-detail-wrap">
            <span class="price h3 text-warning">
              <span class="currency">Minimum Bid: </span><span class="num">{{item.first_bid  | currency:'EUR'}}</span>
            </span>
            
          </p>
          <p>
          <span class="price h3 text">
            <span class="currency">Number of bids:</span><span class="num">{{item.number_of_bids}}</span>
          </span>
          </p>
          <dl class="item-property">
            <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Categories</u></dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="cats" *ngFor="let obj of item.categories"  >
                  {{obj.category}} 
                </div> 
            </dd>
            <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Description</u></dt>
            <dd>
              <p>
                {{item.description}}
              </p>
            </dd>
          </dl>
          <hr>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <dl class="param param-feature">
                <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Started</u></dt>
                <dd>{{item.started | date}}</dd>
                
              </dl> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <dl class="param param-feature">
                <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Ends</u></dt>
                <dd>{{item.ends | date}}</dd>
              </dl>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <dl class="param param-feature">
                <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Location</u></dt>
                <dd>{{item.location}}, {{item.country}}</dd>
                <!-- <dd>{{true == product.outofstock ? 'No': 'Yes'}}</dd> -->
              </dl>  <!-- item-property-hor .// -->
            </div>
          </div>



          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <dl class="param param-inline">
                <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Placed By:</u></dt>
                <dd><p>{{item.seller}}</p></dd>
              </dl>
            </div> <!-- col.// -->
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <dl class="param param-inline">
                <dt class="text-uppercase text-primary"><u>Rating</u></dt>
                <dd><p>...</p></dd>
              </dl>  <!-- item-property .// -->
            </div> <!-- col.// -->
          </div> <!-- row.// -->
          <hr>

          <button class="btns" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary text-uppercase" (click)="openDialog(content)">Place a bid</button>
          <div class="btns" *ngIf="item.buy_price != 0">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success text-uppercase" (click)="onClickBuyNow()">Buy NOW {{item.buy_price | currency:'EUR' }}</button>
          </div>

        </article> <!-- card-body.// -->
      </aside> <!-- col.// -->
    </div> <!-- row.// -->
  </div> <!-- card.// -->
  <div class="table">
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort matSortActive="amount" matSortDirection="desc">
        <!-- no Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="no">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1}} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <!-- Bidder Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="bidder">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bidder </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bidder}} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <!-- Amount Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.amount | currency:'EUR'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
      
        <!-- Date Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.time | date: 'short' :'+0000'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
      
      
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns, sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
  </div>
  <div class="map">
    <app-osm  [location] = "location"> </app-osm>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.gallery-wrap .img-big-wrap img {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}
  
  
.gallery-wrap .img-small-wrap .item-gallery {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 7px 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  
.gallery-wrap .img-small-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
  
.gallery-wrap .img-small-wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}


.cats{
  display:inline;
  font-size: 15;
  font-weight: 500;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btns{
  display:inline;
}

  

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-elevation-z8{
  align-self: center;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What can i do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

using bootstrap

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 border">Cards conten</div>
    <div class="col-6 border">table conatent</div>
    <div class="col-12 border">map content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```